# Show full file name

Tags: total-commander

In case the file/dir name is too long to fit the `Name` column, total commander cuts it and adds `..` at the end.

[image]

Is there a way to configure Total Commander to for example unroll the full name when the file/ dir is selected?

Comment: If you hover over the file name, does it show a tooltip?

Comment: It does not show the tooltip